# Is it good to add a listview inside Persistent bottom sheet in android?

Tags: android, listview, bottom-sheet

I want to design a layout in which the upper section will have elements to get user input and button to save the entered data. On click of the button the entered data will be populated into a listview present in the bottom section. Is it a good design?

Comment: Yeah, there is no problem with this approach. I'm also using the same in my app. One optimization that you can do is, initialize the bottom sheet only once, just keep on changing the data in the listview adapter.

Comment: @Wanted : Thank You. I'll try it.